# Find the closest class and change the previous button to the new button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am doing is when the user clicks on the 'Click me' button then it will find the closest class and change the button name from 'Click me' to 'Remove'. I tried below script but it's not working for me.

```html
<tr>
  <td>asdas</td>
  <td>asdas</td>
  <td>
    <div class="findMe">
      <button type="button" name="renew" class="clickMe">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>asdas</td>
  <td>asdad</td>
  <td>
    <div class="findMe">
      <button type="button" name="renew" class="clickMe">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>asdas</td>
  <td>asdasd</td>
  <td>
    <div class="findMe">
      <button type="button" name="renew" class="clickMe">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickMe').click(function() {
    var changeToRemoveBTN = $(this).closest('tr').find('findMe');
    $.ajax({
      // url:"",
      // method:"POST",
      // data:{},
      success: function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#' + changeToRemoveBTN).html('<button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Missing `.` with class selector, use `.find('.findMe')` also use `changeToRemoveBTN.html(......)`

Comment: @Satpal, Let me try again

Comment: What is `changeToRemoveBTNSec`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I updated that. thanks for the notice

Comment: I tried  $(this).closest('tr').find('.findMe'); but it's not changing the button.

Comment: Ok, now you have another problem because you're appending the `'#'` string to an object, which won't work. You don't need to do that anyway as `changeToRemoveBTN` already holds a reference to the element you want, so just do `changeToRemoveBTN.html(...`

Comment: let me try again.

Comment: Use `var changeToRemoveBTN = $(this).closest('tr').find('.findMe');` and `changeToRemoveBTN.html(...)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes, it's working. There are three issues. first MIssing the dot, second # tag and third is a variable name. Thanks for the help RoryMcCrossan and Satpal

Comment: If you already have changed class selector `findMe` to `.findMe` update your question to get it refreshed.

Comment: Maybe you can simplify your code by : $(this).parent('.findMe');

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('.findMe');
```

This will return the closest DOM element with class '.findMe'.